# Allow clicking of a link inside a jQuery form hint box

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm running a simple jQuery hint tool on my form. **My issue** is that the hint is set to go away when the user clicks away from the input field (on blur). When a user clicks a link inside the hint box, they are "blurring" the input field, **so the box goes away before following the link, so the link never gets followed.**

**Edit: Here's a jFiddle showing my issue with code** http://jsfiddle.net/9pJvp/

The core jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(":input").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("span:nth-child(4)").css('display','inline');
})
$(":input").blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("span:nth-child(4)").css('display','none');
})
```

An example form code that applies this looks like this (the hint is all styled up with css):

```
<tr class="form_row">
    <td class="required_label">
        Example Label:
    </td>
    <td class="input_field">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="blah" />
        <div style="display: inline;"></div>
        <span class="validation_message"></span>
        <span class="hint">
            Blah blah blah <a href="http://www.google.com">heres a link.</a>
            <span class="hint-pointer"></span>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**I've tried adding the following (and variations of it) both INSIDE the `.blur(function() {` and outside it, but neither one works.** Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
$("a").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: jFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/9pJvp/

Comment: FYI finding your `hint` element would be easier by `$(this).siblings(".hint")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = null;
    $(".input_field input, .input_field a").focus(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).closest(".input_field").find("span:nth-child(4)").css('display','inline');
        },3);
    }).blur(function() {
        var self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).closest(".input_field").find("span:nth-child(4)").css('display','none');
        }, 2);
    }).filter("a").bind("focus mousedown", function(e){
        var self = this;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        setTimeout(function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            self.focus();
        }, 1);
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pJvp/3/

It is a bit of a hack and there is probably a better way.

You may have to increase the `setTimeout` intervals to `15`, `30`, and `45` (or higher) - I haven't tested much and am not too sure if all browsers will fire them in the right order (Chrome does).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll do further testing, but it appears to be working on my current browser (Firefox 3.6.24). I don't quite understand what the `setTimeout`'s purpose is here?

Comment: Chose @liho1eye 's answer over yours because his appears to have the same idea, but simpler solution. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Try "long-clicking" the link (click then hold it for a second) on @liho1eye solution, then try the same in mine. Also, try using the `Tab` key on liho1eye's to select the link, then try mine.

Comment: Einstein once said that "everything should be as simple as it can be, but not simpler"... liho1eye's solution is probably too simple. :-)

Comment: I did encounter issues with @liho1eye 's solution even before coming back here. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. So far 100% working with yours. I did use his tip of `var hint = $(this).siblings(".hint");` and I added `.input_field select` to the focus list of yours to account for drop downs (`<select>`). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just [add a delay](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/9pJvp/10/) on blur? Also cleaned up your code a bit for simplicity.

Comment: Perfect. Very clean answer, and thanks for the siblings() tip. I did change the `setTimeout` from 100 to 10 - 10 still allowed the link to be followed, but without the noticeable close delay of 100.

Comment: Try "long-clicking" the link (click then hold it for a second). Also, try using the Tab key to focus and select the link.